# Is there a way to add multiple widgets to a QWidget without writing .addWidget() for multiple lines?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

Currently, I am trying to find out if there is a way to create a list and for each widget in the list to then be added to the QWidget layout.

This is how I though it would work but it is currently only showing the last widget in the list:

```
def HomeWidget(self):
    widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
    layout = QVBoxLayout(widget)

    #title of page
    title = QtWidgets.QLabel('Welcome to the Home Page')
    title.setObjectName('titleOfPage')


    labelTest = QtWidgets.QLabel('TEST')
    labelTest.setObjectName('genText')



    widgetList = [title, labelTest] #all widgets go here
    for widget in widgetList:
        layout.addWidget(widget)

    return widget
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable *widget* in loop conflicting with another variable *widget* in body of function.
Rename *widget* var in your loop, and everything will work fine:

```
def HomeWidget(self):
    widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
    layout = QVBoxLayout(widget)

    #title of page
    title = QtWidgets.QLabel('Welcome to the Home Page')
    title.setObjectName('titleOfPage')


    labelTest = QtWidgets.QLabel('TEST')
    labelTest.setObjectName('genText')



    widgetList = [title, labelTest] #all widgets go here
    for w in widgetList:
        layout.addWidget(w)

    return widget
```

Comment: Thank you! It's really appreciated